# C++ error: no match for 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, cout

Hello I have a problem with this error I cannot understand what's the problem.. So here is full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook(string name)
    {
        setCourseName(name);
    } // end GradeBook constructor

    void setCourseName(string name)
    {
        courseName = name;
    } // end setCourseName

    string getCourseName()
    {
        return courseName; // return object's courseName
    } // end getCourseName

    void displayMessage()
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
    } // end displayMessage
private:
    string courseName;
}; // end class GradeBook

int main()
{
    // create two GradeBook objects
    GradeBook gradeBook1("CS101 Introduction to C++ Programming");
    GradeBook gradeBook2("CS102 Data Structures in C++");

    cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: " << gradeBook1.displayMessage();
}
```

Error part is when I'm trying to print out this line:

```
cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: " << gradeBook1.displayMessage();
```

If I use it just like `gradeBook1.displayMessage();` it prints the message but if I use it in like I showed it gives me nasty error..

Thanks!

Comment: `displayMessage` returns `void`. You can't stream that - it's nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`displayMessage()` is a function who returns `void`. You can't stream this as it's nothing. Just call it in separate lines.

Change

```
cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: " << gradeBook1.displayMessage();
```

to

```
cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: ";
gradeBook1.displayMessage();
```

Comment: Well this works, thank you! But then I'm wondering why that kind of example which is not working is in book.. Thanks

Comment: I strongly recommend you to change the book!

Comment: @user2363241 Just change the book. :P

Comment: @user2363241 For books, look at this list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Okay thanks for answers and suggestions.. I'm going to look for new book.. Good luck )

Answer (score 1):

It gets expanded to :

> cout << `{ cout << "Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl } ;`   which is surely illogical 
>   .

So , use :

> cout << "gradeBook1 created for course: ";
>   gradeBook1.displayMessage();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `<<` operator with  class gradeBook1, overload the operator.
Instead of using the `displayMessage();` method in the class.

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out)
{
     out<<"Welcome to the grade book for\n" << getCourseName() << "!" << endl;
     return out;
}
```

The you can call your object using cout, as follows,

```
cout<<gradeBook1;
```